# How to set ref for SectionList in functional component in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Basically I wanted to use the [scrollToLocation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist#scrolltolocation) method of [SectionList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist), but I can't manage to set the `ref` inside a functional component.

*Note: for the examples below, compulsory properties of SectionList are elided to improve clarity.*

I've tried to use `useRef`, but this does not work, `ref` is still `null` after 3 seconds.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef()
  React.useEffect(() =>
    setTimeout(() => ref.scrollToLocation({itemIndex: 0, sectionIndex: 0}, 3000)
  )
  return (
    <SectionList ref={ref} />
  )
}
```

I've also tried to put the ref inside state, but this also does not work, as it results in maximum update depth exceeded:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ref: null})
  React.useEffect(() =>
    setTimeout(() => ref.scrollToLocation({itemIndex: 0, sectionIndex: 0}, 3000)
  )
  return (
    <SectionList ref={ref => setState(state => ({...state, ref}))} />
  )
}
```

Then, I also tried to using a plain variable, but that does not work too, as `ref` is still `null` after 3 seconds.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  let ref;
  React.useEffect(() =>
    setTimeout(() => ref.scrollToLocation({itemIndex: 0, sectionIndex: 0}, 3000)
  )
  return (
    <SectionList ref={r => ref = r} />
  )
}
```

Therefore I'm wondering if there is a way to get the ref of a SectionList inside a functional component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a ref of the Any React Component, we can use the useRef hook to store the reference of the component to call methods or access or set the properties of React Component.

To access the reference of React component using the useRef hook, we can access the reference by the current property.

as like:

```
ref.current.scrollToLocation({  itemIndex: 0, sectionIndex: 0 })
```

Have a try with the below code:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef()

  React.useEffect(() => {
     ref.current?.scrollToLocation({itemIndex: 0, sectionIndex: 0}
  })
  
  return (
    <SectionList ref={ref} />
  )
}
```

we can use the ? symbol if prevent a crash if the method or property not available in the object from where we are trying to access it.

Comment: where is `getItemLayout`. It will crash without it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the first example is actually correct, the only thing I got wrong is forgot to access the `current` property of `ref` before invoking `scrollToLocation`.

The correct code should be:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef()
  React.useEffect(() =>
    setTimeout(() => ref.current.scrollToLocation({itemIndex: 0, sectionIndex: 0}, 3000)
                       //^^^^^^^Adding this make things work
  )
  return (
    <SectionList ref={ref} />
  )
}
```